# Windows Azure - Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext'

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

Following this blog with steps by steps http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/#setupdevenv

If I run from my local machine then i see the data which is coming from Windows Azure db and i can add and update or delete ... perfectly working fine but the problem is when I publish my application to Windows Azure and I able to see my page and all the static pages are working fine but except one page which is interacting with database.

here is my web.config connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=tcp:* insert server name*.database.windows.net,1433;Database=* insert database name *;User ID=*insert username *@* insert server name*;Password={*insert password here *};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"  />
```

I get this message when i try to access the page from http://XXXX.azurewebsites.net/Employee

Error Message:

```
Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your database cannot be created automatically. The fastest way to fix that is to follow the suggestion from your error message. Open your **Package Manager Console** with the project, which contains the connection string and the **Configuration.cs** (your migrations), selected as the startup project and run **Update-Database**. It could be that you must pass some parameters to this command if you have changed something on your migrations.